# How many transaction I can push to EOSIO

Tags: nodeos

I read the EOSIO has maximum 3996 TPS, what does that mean?

If so, I can push 3996 transaction to EOS simultaneously?

Comment: Those trx were very light trx's, if you tried pushing that many real trx's you would break the chain.  1000 trx/s is a realistic benchmark for peak trx's at the moment before EOS VM is implemented. https://vimeo.com/266585781

Comment: Thank Nat,
So If I must break it partly, then push to blockchain.
For example: I have 10000 trx, I break it to 10 times, I will push 1000 and wait 1s and so on.
is it okay?